# Getting shipping price in specific currency on Shippo

Tags: shippo, dhl

When using [Shippo API](http://goshippo.com) for buying postage and printing shipping labels, shipping rates are returned in the currency of the country you're shipping from. So if you're shipping from Europe they will show in Euro, if you're shipping from United States they will show up in USD.

Is there an API option to show the shipping cost in a different currency (for example, always US dollars)? This problem appears when we display prices for goods in USD, so we need to show the shipping cost in the same currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the rate to the currency of your choice by adding the currency code to the URL as described in the API docs: https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#rates